# UIPanGestureRecognizer beyondBounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, frame, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have this code that retrieves the coordinates of an object when it is panned:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *moveBuildingTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveobject:)];
```

Method moveobject contents:

```
CGPoint tapPoint=[recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
```

I use this to change the frame of - move it -an imageview using these coordinates.

However, upon dragging the image around - triggering the `uipangesturerecognizer` action, I found that when I drag it to the absolute bottom, I get an error that -[UIPanGestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:inView:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0).

How can I solve this exception and prevent the user from dragging past this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weird that your `moveobject:` method gets called even though the private touches array of the gesture recognizer seems to be empty.

Anyway, in general, if you don't handle multitouch gestures within gesture recognizer, I would suggest to use `[recognizer locationInView:]` rather then `locationOfTouch:inView:`.

Btw:

Your talking about a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` while in the code you're using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

The code I would recommend to handle dragging of a particular view looks like this:

```
//...
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[someView addGestureRecognizer:panGR];
//...

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    CGPoint translation = [gr translationInView:gr.view];
    gr.view.frame = CGRectOffset(gr.view.frame, translation.x, translation.y);
    [gr setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:gr.view];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the `numberOfTouches` in your `UIGestureRecognizer` like:

```
if (recognizer.numberOfTouches) {
      CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the number of touches would be 0 if UIGestureRecognizer.state is began ?